# Problem with batch file doesn't detect file

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, batch-file

I have a problem with my program, I don't know how can I make it detect that the file `NewFile(%i%)` exists.

```
    for /l %%i in (1, 1, 100) do (

    if EXIST NewFile(%i%).txt (
    echo "New file"> NewFile(%%i).txt
    goto EndLoop
    )
    
    if EXIST NewFile.txt(
    echo "New file"> NewFile(%%i).txt
    goto EndLoop
    ) else (
    echo "New file"> NewFile.txt
    goto EndLoop
    )
)
```

It says ") was unexpected at this time." 
How can I fix this?

Comment: That's not gonna work. All `%` surrounded variables are evaluated before the loop even runs, so they will not update every time the loop runs. You need to research `delayedexpansion` in DOS batch files and use `!` inside the loop instead of `%`. More info: https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html

Comment: @Ruslan. `delayedexpansion` is needed when a variable is `set` inside a code block. the changing variable needs to be evaluated at execution time and therefore we enable it, nothing get's set inside the loop here, so not the issue here at all.

Comment: Do not confuse `for` meta-variables with normal environment variables, hence `%i%` must read `%%i`…

Answer (score 1):

You currently have a few issues, of which the first is the one causing the issue you experienced, but the others will also cause the script to not function. You have a `for` loop with a parathesis inside the loop, `for` is expecting that loop as the ending parenthesis of the loop. So you would need to escape that closing parenthesis as `if EXIST NewFile(%%i^).txt (`

You also have an invalid `%i%` in the first `if` statement. it should be `%%i`
The line `if EXIST NewFile.txt(` should have a space before the opening parenthesis.

```
@echo off
for /l %%i in (1,1,100) do (
    if EXIST "NewFile(%%i^).txt" (
    echo "New file"> NewFile(%%i^).txt
    goto :EndLoop
   )
   if EXIST NewFile.txt (
       echo "New file"> NewFile(%%i^).txt
       goto EndLoop
   ) else (
       echo "New file"> NewFile.txt
       goto :EndLoop
   )
)
```

Then, the `goto`'s as I am not sure what you want to achieve there, but just to make sure you know, if it finds one file that matches it will exit the loop. If that is your intention then that is fine, if you want to perform the action on all the numbers, you should not have the `goto` there.

Comment: Thanks man, the "goto" was for exiting the loop, I'm new at batch programing so I didin't know how to end the loop.

Comment: ok, so then remove the `goto`s in the loop for processing all the numbers. Did the code as it is work for you though?

Comment: Thanks it did work now it's just making 100 files but I think I can fix that :)

Comment: yes, because of the counter of counting in from `1`, in `1`'s to `100`. to do more, increase the counter. If I understood your requirement, I could probably have given a better solution instead of using a generic counter.